# How to prevent class selector from attaching to particular element?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fix an issue with this image carousel. I have the typical "next" and "previous" buttons. When the button is clicked the JavaScript adds the class "current" to the proceeding div and removes it from the current one which makes the "current" opacity "1" and the rest "0".

The next button works fine. It cycles through all the divs continuously and starts back at the beginning. However, the previous button adds the "current" class to the logo that sits on top of the banner. This makes the logo sort of act as a banner image. I used nth-child(2) to start because technically the first child is the logo image.

What is the best option for fixing this? Thank you.

```
**HTML**

<div class="banner">
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo-hollow.png" alt="logo">
    
        <div class="banner-slide current"></div>
        <div class="banner-slide"></div>
        <div class="banner-slide"></div>
        <div class="banner-slide"></div>
        <div class="banner-slide"></div>
    </div>
```

```
**CSS**

.banner-slide {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }

.banner-slide.current {
    opacity: 1;
}

.banner-slide:nth-child(2) {
    background: url('../img/slider-1.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner-slide:nth-child(3) {
    background: url('../img/slider-2.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner-slide:nth-child(4) {
    background: url('../img/slider-3.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner-slide:nth-child(5) {
    background: url('../img/slider-4.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.banner-slide:nth-child(6) {
    background: url('../img/slider-5.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}
```

```
**JavaScript**

const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.banner-slide');
const next = document.querySelector('#next');
const prev = document.querySelector('#prev');

const nextSlide = () => {
  // Get Current Class
  const current = document.querySelector('.current');
  // Remove Current Class
  current.classList.remove('current');
  // Check for next slide
  if(current.nextElementSibling) {
    // Add current to next sibling
    current.nextElementSibling.classList.add('current');
  } else {
    // Add current to start
    slides[0].classList.add('current');
  }
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
}

const prevSlide = () => {
  // Get Current Class
  const current = document.querySelector('.current');
  // Remove Current Class
  current.classList.remove('current');
  // Check for prev slide
  if(current.previousElementSibling) {
    // Add current to next sibling
    current.previousElementSibling.classList.add('current');
  } else {
    // Add current to last
    slides[slides.length - 1].classList.add('current');
  }
  setTimeout(() => current.classList.remove('current'));
};

// Button Events
next.addEventListener('click', e => {
  nextSlide();
});

prev.addEventListener('click', e => {
  prevSlide();
});
```